# After login into my website protractor unable to find next element

Tags: protractor, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

This code for after login user should post some hello message.

```
describe("launching Telekha",function(){
    it("navigating to signin page",function(){
        browser.get("www");
        element(by.model("credentials.email")).sendKeys("abnsd6@gmail.com");
        element(by.model("credentials.password")).sendKeys("123456");
        var ptr = element( by.css('[ng-click="login()"]') );
        ptr.click();
        });

    it("on dashboard",function(){
        element(by.model("post.postText")).sendKeys("hello");
            element( by.css('[ng-click="postit()"]') ).click();
        });
});
```

**HTML code for the button**

```
<textarea id="post-editor" placeholder="Tell your friends" ng-model="post.postText" class="textareanoborder col-xs-12 col-md-12 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false"> </textarea>
```

Comment: what is the error thrown?

Comment: Did you add ignoreSynchronization = true; somewhere, @Ajay?

Comment: No.it is required @TomNijs

Comment: I'm just wondering what might cause your error "protractor failed to synchronize..."

Comment: Thanks @Tom it resolved with  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but from experience it usually isn't far off. When the page you are navigating to is loaded, are there any animations, AJAX requests or other delays, separate from AngularJS that might be occurring? Protractor does not wait for these and will execute the code:

```
element(by.model("post.postText")).sendKeys("hello");
```

as soon as it can. If when this is executed, all the animations have not yet been completed, you element will not be visible to protractor and you'll see the error you've encountered.

To quickly test this, add a `browser.sleep(10000);` before the line where it's failing. `browser.sleep();` is a command that will force the browser to wait for a set amount of time, in this case 10.000 milliseconds (10 seconds).

If this does end up working, you might want to change it to something more elegant such as:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.model("post.postText")).isPresent();
}, 10000);
```

Which will wait for your element to become visible, but only for a maximum of 10 seconds, after which it will continue anyway.

**EDIT1: (which works fine):**

**HTML (Serving from http://localhost:8080)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <textarea id="post-editor" placeholder="Tell your friends" ng-model="post.postText" class="textareanoborder col-xs-12 col-md-12 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false"> </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

**spec.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
    $("#post-editor").sendKeys("testlol");
    browser.sleep(2000);
  });
});
```

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
};
```

Comment: Thannks for the info,i have a service request to login and post text.@Tom

Comment: Did adding the browser.sleep() line fix things?

Comment: No.please help me to out@Tom

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you double checked the element selectors for typos, have you checked how long your service request takes and when exactly your protractor test is failing?

Comment: browser.wait() function executing perfectly when sendKeys("hello") to the model it is not finding the element

Comment: i tried all the ways,it is executing all the steps which am sending but the problem is it is not sending the keys to the browser like sendKeys("hello")

Comment: Is your element inside an iFrame? And as @SureshSalloju mentioned, please include the relevant HTML code.

Comment: <textarea  id="post-editor" placeholder="Tell your friends" ng-model="post.postText" class="textareanoborder col-xs-12 col-md-12 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">                </textarea>

Comment: Your question title says "unable to find element". Is this the error message you're receiving or does it say "cannot focus element"?

Comment: facing following error @Tom  Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="post-editor"]).
    The following tasks were pending:

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()** method to wait until element is visible on UI and then send data to input field.

```
    var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    it("on dashboard",function(){
       var ele=element(by.id("post-editor"));
       browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele),8000,'Ele is not presented');
       ele.sendKeys("hello");
       element( by.css('[ng-click="postit()"]') ).click();
    });
```

Comment: Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: by.model("post.postText").    
     - $timeout: function (){i(b)}
     - $timeout: function (){i(b)}
     - $timeout: function (){i(b)}
     - $timeout: function (){i(b)}
     - $timeout: function (){i(b)}
     - $timeout: function c(){var b=a.data(sa);if(b){for(var c=1;c<b.length;c++)b[c]();a.removeData(sa)}}
     - $timeout: function c(){var b=a.data(sa);if(b){for(va

Comment: if i increase wait time also it's throwing an error

Comment: @Ajay, can check in which tag the 'ng-app' directive is placed?(either in login.thml or index.html)

Comment: it is in index.html

Comment: in which tag 'ng-app' is placed? is in <html> or <body> or any other tag

Comment: in body tag is there any problem?if i place it in body

Comment: Protractor bydefault look for ng-app in body tag. If ng-app not in the body, you will get that error. It can be set manually. but in your case, it will not a problem. can you add browser.sleep(8000) after login operation.

Comment: it is executing the steps perfectly but unable to send the post. i mean  what i am sending is unable to show.i am sending sendKeys("hello") message.@suresh

Comment: can u put the html code relate to that input field?

Comment: <textarea id="post-editor" placeholder="Tell your friends" ng-model="post.postText" class="textareanoborder col-xs-12 col-md-12 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">                </textarea>

Comment: Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="post-editor"]).
    The following tasks were pending:
\
    ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 50 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=
      
2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 68.389 seconds

Comment: Thanks for helping @suresh

Comment: @Ajay, shall we have call at 7PM IST. i can help to resolve it